# angularjs and calling function in the same object

Tags: angularjs

I use two simple form with angularjs

```
<form ng-controller="ctrs.ctr1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" />{{getName()}}
</form>
```

and

```
<form ng-controller="ctrs.ctr2">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ng-model="name" />{{getName()}}
</form>
```

and s small script for e.g showing name twice

```
var ctrs = {
    nameTwoTimes: function(name) {
        return name+" "+name;
    },
    ctr1: function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.getName = function() {
            return $scope.name+" "+$scope.name;
        };
    },
    ctr2: function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.getName = function() {
            this.nameTwoTimes($scope.name);
        };
    }
};
```

How to use the function nameTwoTimes, that in calling it is not "undefined"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
var nameTwoTimes: function(name) {
    return name+" "+name;
};
var ctrs = {        
    ctr1: function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.getName = function() {
            return $scope.name+" "+$scope.name;
        };
    },
    ctr2: function($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.getName = function() {
            nameTwoTimes($scope.name);
        };
    }
};
```

Comment: In a ctrs json is not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.